# Detect USB devices event

Tags: wmi, guid, wql

I made a console application which detects plugin and plugout events for all type of usb devices. but I wanted some filteration in it like I wanted to detect only webcams . This was done by using GUID class. The class for webcam is 'Image' class with GUID "{6bdd1fc5-810f-11d0-bec7-08002be2092f}" .The problem is that this 'Image' class is also used for scanners and I dont want to detect scanners.The code is given below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WqlEventQuery weqQuery = new WqlEventQuery();
        weqQuery.EventClassName = "__InstanceOperationEvent";
        weqQuery.WithinInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);
        weqQuery.Condition = @"TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_PnPEntity'";

        ManagementEventWatcher m_mewWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(weqQuery);
        m_mewWatcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(m_mewWatcher_EventArrived);

        m_mewWatcher.Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void m_mewWatcher_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool bUSBEvent = false;
        string deviceCaption = "";
        string deviceType = "";

        foreach (PropertyData pdData in e.NewEvent.Properties)
        {
            try
            {
                ManagementBaseObject mbo = (ManagementBaseObject)pdData.Value;
                if (mbo != null)
                {

                    foreach (PropertyData pdDataSub in mbo.Properties)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine(pdDataSub.Name + " = " + pdDataSub.Value);
                        if (pdDataSub.Name == "Caption")
                        {
                            deviceCaption = pdDataSub.Value.ToString();
                        }
                        if (pdDataSub.Name == "ClassGuid" && pdDataSub.Value.ToString() == "{6bdd1fc5-810f-11d0-bec7-08002be2092f}")
                        {
                            bUSBEvent = true;
                            deviceType = "Image";
                        }
                    }
                    if (bUSBEvent)
                    {
                        if (e.NewEvent.ClassPath.ClassName == "__InstanceCreationEvent")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("A " + deviceType + " device " + deviceCaption + " was plugged in at " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                        }
                        else if (e.NewEvent.ClassPath.ClassName == "__InstanceDeletionEvent")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("A " + deviceType + " device " + deviceCaption + " was plugged out at " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

[for references check this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553426%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I waited but no body answered this question so, after seeing all properties of **ManagementBaseObject** I found that there is a property named **Service** which is different for scanners. In scanners the value of Service property is **usbscan** while in cameras it is usbvideo.
eg.
you can do something like this

```
if (mbo.Properties["Service"].Value.ToString() == "usbscan")
{
//then it means it is a scanner
}
else
{
//then it means it is a camera
}
```

**note:** The main question was that how can we differentiate between a scanner and a webcam because they both use same GUID.